# How Java8's Collection.parallelStream works?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

`Collection` class comes with a new method "`parallelStream`" in Java SDK 8.

It is obvious that this new method provides a mechanism to consume collections in parallel.

But, I wonder about how Java achieve this parallelism. What is the underlying mechanism? Is it simply a multithreaded execution? Or does fork/join framework (coming with Java SDK 7) step in? If the answer is neither then, how does it work and what are the advantages of it over the other two mechanisms?

Comment: You can check the source code, you know...

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the stream’s parallel method, you may wonder where the threads used by the parallel stream come from, how many there are, and how you can customize the process. Parallel streams internally use the default `ForkJoinPool`, which by default has as many threads as you have processors, as returned by `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()`. But you can change the size of this pool using the system property `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism`.

The infrastructure used behind the scenes by parallel streams to execute operations in parallel is the fork/join framework introduced in Java 7. It’s vital to have a good understanding of the parallel stream internals in order to use them correctly. The fork/join framework was designed to recursively split a parallelizable task into smaller tasks and then combine the results of each subtask to produce the overall result. It’s an implementation of the `ExecutorService` interface, which distributes those
subtasks to worker threads in a thread pool, called `ForkJoinPool`.

The `Spliterator` stands for “splitable iterator.” Like Iterators, Spliterators are used to traverse the elements of a source, but they’re also designed to do this in parallel. Although you may not have to develop your own Spliterator in practice, understanding how to do so will give you a wider understanding about how parallel streams work.

The algorithm that splits a Stream into multiple parts is a recursive process. In the first step, a method called `trySplit` is invoked on the first Spliterator and generates a second one. Then in step 2 it’s called again on these two Spliterators, which results in a total of four. The framework keeps invoking the method trySplit on a Spliterator until it returns null to signal that the data
structure that it’s processing is no longer divisible. Finally, this recursive splitting process terminates when all Spliterators have returned null to a trySplit invocation.

The last abstract method declared by the Spliterator interface is characteristics, which returns an int encoding the set of characteristics of the Spliterator itself. The Spliterator clients can use these characteristics to better control and optimize its usage. They are: `ORDERED`, `DISTINCT`, `SORTED`,
`SIZED`, `NONNULL`, `IMMUTABLE`, `CONCURRENT`, and `SUBSIZED`. Depending on the specific characteristics of a stream, it may in fact not run in parallel at all.

The book that explains all this in detail is: [Java 8 in Action: Lambdas, streams, and functional-style programming
(Raoul-Gabriel Urma, Mario Fusco, and Alan Mycroft)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617291994), from Manning. See Chapter 7:
**Parallel data processing and performance**.

Answer (score 1):

> But, I wonder about how Java achieve this parallelism. What is the underlying mechanism? Is it simply a multithreaded execution? Or does
>   fork/join framework (coming with Java SDK 7) step in? If the answer is
>   neither then, how does it work and what are the advantages of it over
>   the other two mechanisms?

As far as I know it is based on the fork/join framework (coming with Java SDK 7).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember it's not guaranteed that you're going to get parallel stream that really does something multithreaded way.
If collection can be divided into separate tasks, then Fork/Join framework will kick in, if not, then you're going to get serial stream.

To check different collections you could run parallel stream on each and System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()) something from inside. Output should be something like: Thread[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-%d%]