# When parallel streams are combined together java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, parallel-processing, java-stream

I have a doubt  when are all the streams combined to get the result?
If I have employee class and have to get top 5 employee ids with max salary, I can do using parallel stream but how does it work internally?

Following is the code. How it works internally? According to me, it is obvious that parallel streams are created at `listA.parallelStream()` this time but when are the combined together?

```
List<Employee> listA =  new ArrayList<Employee>();
listA.parallelStream()
     .sorted(((e1,e2) -> e2.salary.compareTo(e1.salary)))
     .filter(e1 -> e1.salary > 50000)
     .limit(5)
     .map(e -> e.eID)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: They're combined in the collector, using its "combiner".

Comment: When code is written declaratively, the implementation takes care of the details. You say "I want this list to be processed in parallel, and a single result should be collected at the end", without caring about the "how". The implementation takes care of synchronizing those threads to pull one result. In other words, if you need to know how it works, look at the applicable implementation's code or documentation.

Comment: The `Collectors.toList` has a combiner to add to Slaw's comment such as `(left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; }`

Comment: @slaw So according  to that is limit(5) and map also calculated in individual streams ?

Comment: @Namn so once limit is calculated first and then all streams are combined then how it will ensure that it gives only 5 records?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Java8's Collection.parallelStream works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634825/how-java8s-collection-parallelstream-works)

Comment: @Naman - I am trying to understand how OPs code works when joining the sub-lists in a parallel stream. The elements of each sub-list get sorted. But, how do the sub-lists get joined in the correct order? Which method of stream joins the sub-lists in sorted order?

Answer (score 0):

Parallel or sequential is a property of the "full" stream, not a portion of it. Thus, all the computation chain (the pipeline) is done in parallel from the source that is splitted to an appropriate degree (in general the default number of thread in the fork/join pool), up to the terminal operation (collect/resume) that is a contention point where everything is gathered from the parallel chain. Thus when a data is claimed to the source and one is produced, that data is injected to a pipeline managed by a dedicated thread (there is no "data move" in between threads).

Then in your example, for example the `sorted` operation will only sort what a given thread will see passing through it.